# ADA handle NFT royalty address

Tags: nft, smart-contract

Is it possible to use an ADA handle as the address for NFT royalties? I’d like a way of changing the address that royalties get sent to if I decide to sell my project in the future. Maybe it would be possible to do this through a smart contract instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. You can make a script address where royalties are send to with an Ada handle in the datum. The script only permits grabbing those funds if the corresponding ada handle is part of the transaction.

With the upcoming HF (cip 31) you can even make it so that the script can allow grabbing by anyone as long as the destination of the funds are the same as the referenced utxo that contains the ada handle. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

[AdaHandles](https://docs.adahandle.com/quick-start#querying-a-handle) are used to query the blockchain with either Block Frost or DB-Sync to find the wallet containing the NFT, in this case it would depend on how the marketplace uses the metadata in the [CIP-27](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/tree/master/CIP-0027) royalty token.